# How to Update React State and Immediately Use Its State On a Button Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was building a simple component in React (Native) and have noticed an issue with my code. Supposedly, we have a state that will be realiable for our search value on a page:

```
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('')
```

and we have a `TextInput` component (`input` on web) that has following props:

```
<TextInput
    value={searchValue}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    onPressClear={onPressClear}
/>
```

here we define the functions:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
  console.log('searchValue is:' + searchValue)
  callApi(searchValue)
}

const onChangeText = (text: string) => {
  setSearchValue(text)
}

const onPressClear = () => {
  onChangeText('')
  onSubmit();
}
```

now, this component almost works correctly, but I want to request API call after i'm clearing the search, and i am calling submit function when i'm done. Obviously, the state would not be updated at that point because the state has not been changed in submit function. When i would press clear button (if i have something in `searchValue`), i would not get a cleared state.

Wrapping the state and calling the submit function in `useEffect` with `searchValue` dependency is not good for us because we only want to track the submission.

What is the correct solution here to get empty `searchValue` in submit function when we cleared the state?

Comment: Why you just dont add `setSearchValue(text)` in the `onPressClear` function instead of  `onChangeText('')?` Add in that line ` that has following params:` remember that those are `props` not `params`

Comment: replace `onSubmit()` in `onPressClear` with `callApi('')` should work

Comment: @S.Marx sorry, poor words choice from my side, i have edited the question. About your answer: i replaced it with `setSearchValue('')` and the effect is still the same.

Comment: @Kriss_Vector what if there are calculations that would like to do with search values or something before i call api request? Is the only solution to duplicate the call for API?

Comment: @denistepp then you can modify `onSubmit` a bit, add a param like `isClear` => `onSubmit(isClear=false) { if(isClear){...} ...}`, then call `onSubmit(true)` in `onPressClear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');
  const [isFormCleared, setIsFormCleared] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log('searchValue is: ' + searchValue);
    callApi(searchValue);
  };

  const onChangeText = (text: string) => {
    setSearchValue(text);
    setIsFormCleared(false);
  };

  const onPressClear = () => {
    setSearchValue('');
    setIsFormCleared(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFormCleared) {
      onSubmit();
    }
  }, [isFormCleared]);

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={searchValue}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      onPressClear={onPressClear}
    />
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: This will make the `onSubmit` called when rendered.

Comment: your correct, i  edited the answer.

Comment: why `onChangeText` has `setIsFormCleared` every time the value changes? is there a case when it would go to `true` while editing text?